# Deleting a property from a node in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I want to remove a property from a node.

Using "removeProperty(NodeRef nodeRef, QName qname)" i can remove it, but i don't know will it cause any problem(like data correption, indexing issue or something ).

Can anyone please help me

Comment: can you share a code snippet? the error you're getting ?

Comment: Thanks Younes. 
i didnt try it out. when i searched, i found "removeProperty(NodeRef nodeRef, QName qname)". Before trying i just want to know will there be any data correption or somthing because of this, so that i can take some precautions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, no - it won't cause any data corruption or indexing issues. One caveat to this, the data model will not allow you to remove mandatory properties (you'll get an error if you attempt to do this). It will not cause any issues with indexing.

Comment: Thanks Dave :) i will try to remove the property and comment if anything unusual happens.